# how to add a link in a meta text multiline

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, splistitem

I've a document library and inside a column multiline text.
I've to set a link to an url.

I've tried to set my item with.

```
item["col"] = "<a href='myurl'>link</a>";
```

Sometime it works but in an other lib i've to write

```
item["col"] = myrulWithoutSpace;
```

My column is in a content type and use in bot lib